Chromedriver update (129.0) is not hiding the window
my window hiding code, which works in all chromedriver versions, is no longer functional.
It doesn't work with the latest 129 update.
My selenium version : 4.0.0b3 and old solution:
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
options.add_argument('log-level=3')
driver_path = "C:/chromedriver.exe"
chrome_service = ChromeService(driver_path)
chrome_service.creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW

I would like to ask for your support on solutions. Chromedriver window should not open in any way

This question is similar to: Chrome 129 Headless shows blank window. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
